# Which healing power is more powerful, Percival's or Tristan's?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Both Percival and Tristan have healing powers. However, they aren't the same. Tristan's healing power comes from his angel ancestry, and Percival's comes from his magic power "Hope".

Which healing power is more powerful, Percival's or Tristan's?